# Modifying JSON Hierarchy to move a key down and convert it into a K/V pair C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Essentially I need to have this:

```
    "/xxx/dynamicFileName1": {
    "lines": {
        "total": 8,
        "covered": 4,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 50
    },
    "functions": {
        "total": 1,
        "covered": 0,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 0
    },
    "statements": {
        "total": 8,
        "covered": 4,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 50
    },
    "branches": {
        "total": 2,
        "covered": 0,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 0
    }
},
"/xxx/dynamicFileName2": {
    "lines": {
        "total": 13,
        "covered": 4,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 30.77
    },
    "functions": {
        "total": 1,
        "covered": 0,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 0
    },
    "statements": {
        "total": 13,
        "covered": 4,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 30.77
    },
    "branches": {
        "total": 12,
        "covered": 0,
        "skipped": 0,
        "pct": 0
    }
}
```

Turn into this: (The dynamic file name key is moved down and used as the value in a key value pair)

```
{
"results": [{
        "Name": "/xxx/dynamicFileName1",
        "lines": {
            "total": 3321,
            "covered": 853,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 25.69
        },
        "statements": {
            "total": 3327,
            "covered": 853,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 25.64
        },
        "functions": {
            "total": 724,
            "covered": 36,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 4.97
        },
        "branches": {
            "total": 1984,
            "covered": 42,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 2.12
        }
    },
    {
        "Name": "/xxx/dynamicFileName2",
        "lines": {
            "total": 3321,
            "covered": 853,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 25.69
        },
        "statements": {
            "total": 3327,
            "covered": 853,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 25.64
        },
        "functions": {
            "total": 724,
            "covered": 36,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 4.97
        },
        "branches": {
            "total": 1984,
            "covered": 42,
            "skipped": 0,
            "pct": 2.12
        }
    }
]}
```

I'm trying to deserialize the above JSON into classes.
Wondering if anyone has dealt with a problem like this before? I've been reading the NewtonSoft docs and I haven't been able to piece anything together. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Deserialize in `Dictionary<string, object>`, do the transformation and reserialize.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here?  Are you trying to *transform* the first JSON into the second JSON?  Or are you just trying to deserialize the first JSON into a class structure that resembles the second JSON?

Comment: @BrianRogers deserialize the first JSON into a class structure that resembles the second JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class structure that corresponds to the second JSON is the following:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Statistics Lines { get; set; }
    public Statistics Statements { get; set; }
    public Statistics Functions { get; set; }
    public Statistics Branches { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Covered { get; set; }
    public int Skipped { get; set; }
    public float Pct { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code you would need to deserialize the first JSON to this class structure.  It loads the JSON into a `JObject`, moves each of the dynamic keys into a `Name` property on its respective child object, collects the child objects into a list, and finally places the list into a new `RootObject` instance.

```
var root = new RootObject
{
    Results = JObject.Parse(json)
        .Properties()
        .Select(jp =>
        {
            JObject item = (JObject)jp.Value;
            item.AddFirst(new JProperty("Name", jp.Name));
            return item.ToObject<Result>();
        })
        .ToList()
};
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/30xova

Comment: Thanks Brian, I modified the code you wrote to suit my own projects interfaces and classes but this helped tremendously. Accepted this as the answer

Comment: Glad I could help!